# Как сделать горизонтальные блоки картинки со ссылкой и текстом внизу

Tags: html

Как сделать горизонтальные блоки картинки со ссылкой и текстом внизу , примерно как здесь http://joxi.ru/DmB4lVpiEzJBAP, ссылками являются сама картинка, и красный заголовок под ней , а затем еще текст.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<ul>
<li style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://idrawing.ru/images/articles/449-serious-kevin/serious-kevin.jpg" style="width: 50px;" />
    <p>Text</p>
  </a>
</li>
<li style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://idrawing.ru/images/articles/449-serious-kevin/serious-kevin.jpg" style="width: 50px;" />
    <p>Text</p>
  </a>
</li>
<li style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://idrawing.ru/images/articles/449-serious-kevin/serious-kevin.jpg" style="width: 50px;" />
    <p>Text</p>
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
```